# How to create a Share button in SpriteKit/Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am kind of new to Spritekit, and I am creating a game where I have a image of a share button where I want the user to click on it to show the `UIActivityViewController`.  I know how to do it in UIKit, but not in SpriteKit.

[image: The Image]

> here is my code.

```
      // var ShareButton : UIButton!


 ShareButton = UIButton.init(frame: CGRectMake(self.view!.frame.size.width/2 - 80,self.view!.frame.size.height/2 + 140 , 163, 54))

    ShareButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "share"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    ShareButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressedShareButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.view!.addSubview(ShareButton)



     func pressed(_ sender: UIButton!) {


     let va = self.view?.window?.rootViewController

     let myText = "Can you beat my score \(score) in this game.  "

     let activityVC:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myText], applicationActivities: nil)

     va?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)




     }
```

Comment: What is the actually issue here? Where does this code come from?

Comment: The code comes from my `GameOver` scene.

Comment: All I want to do is when they click on the image which is a button, that shows the `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: First you should use something like this to call `pressed` method : `ShareButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("pressed:"), for: .touchUpInside)`

Comment: Or in a latest Swift : `ShareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameScene.pressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)`

Comment: is my code above correct? How will you tackle to this problem, with spritekit from an image?

Comment: You didn't answer about what is the actual issue?

Comment: Billy Jr.  I think you want to take this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com.  Stackoverflow is for questions and answers to problems, code review is where you go to get your code reviewed and ask for improvement tips.